# WSS4JInInterceptor using base64 certificate

Tags: java, soap, cxf

I have to send a SOAP request to a secured web service and I was provided a client certificate in base64 format. How do I go about using this for securing calls to the web service in Java? I'm using CXF client and Grails 1.3.7. I want to be able to encrypt or add the certificate to my SOAP requests like this:

```
Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ENC_PROP_FILE, "client-keystore.properties");
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ENC_KEY_ID, "DirectReference");
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.ENCRYPT);
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ENCRYPTION_USER, "myAlias");
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ENC_SYM_ALGO, "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc");
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ENC_KEY_TRANSPORT, "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5");
WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
client.getEndpoint().getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
```

So that the web service can authenticate my requests. I'm not quite familiar with using interceptors on soap messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can BASE-64 decode the certificate, and import it into a keystore, which you reference in your client-keystore.properties.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with another solution for this. First thing I did was to read the base64 string from properties file, parse it and save to a pfx file:

```
// certStr = base64 string from properties file
byte[] cert = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(certStr);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/mycert.pfx"));
fos.write(cert);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Then used it as a keystore:

```
// keystore file
File keyFile = new File("C:/mycert.pfx");
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
InputStream keyInput = new FileInputStream(keyFile);
keyStore.load(keyInput, pKeyPassword.toCharArray());
keyInput.close();
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, pKeyPassword.toCharArray());
KeyManager[] km = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(km, null, new java.security.SecureRandom());
SSLSocketFactory sslFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory);
```

The certificate was added to my SOAP request and I didn't have to encrypt the request after all. Reference [here](http://www.rap.ucar.edu/staff/paddy/cacerts/index.html).